In theory, is it possible to elucidate crystal structure using IR data with an accuracy comparable to XRD or are there fundamental limitations?
Obviously, IR is extremely hard to fully interpret for all but the simplest molecules, so that's more of a theoretical question, but... In principle, IR contains all the data about chemical structure as even different polymorphs of the same compound have different IR spectra. So the question is: is it theoretically possible to use IR data instead of XRD data to decode a crystal structure? I am pretty sure that it's theoretically possible at the very least with some accuracy, but would it be possible to get the same accuracy you get with XRD? Or are there fundamental (and not just practical) limitations such as natural line width limiting accuracy for instance, I imagine the latter would be mitigated by the fact that you can use multiple IR bands.

@Mithoron All right, but why exactly is it not possible even in theory? What fundamental limitations make it impossible?

You know what, maybe it's possible, but more difficult https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infrared_Nanospectroscopy_(AFM-IR)

But it's still worse than XRD, NMR or SAXS.

IR and Raman & microwave measure bond frequencies and infer bond lengths from a model of a bonds behaviour, not atomic positions. XRD measures atomic positions but not frequency. You can get structure from special types of NMR spectroscopy because NMR is sensitive to interaction between non directly connected atoms which IR etc are not.

@porphyrin but in principle, vibrational bands are affected by different crystal packing (in different polymorphs for instance), and IR spectra are still affected by interactions between non-directly connected atoms, albeit not to the same extent as NMR... perhaps, I misunderstand.

Affected by this and that , yes, but these effects do not lead to a structure, i.e. positions of atoms because  IR  inherently only gives frequencies (i.e. differences in energy between vibrational levels) and so  shape of potential (influenced by neighbouring bonds maybe) but only if enough lines are available to measure, so normally only in gas phase. Rotational spectroscopy can give average bond lengths (but not geometry) but for any molecule with more than a few atoms the lines overlap by so much it becomes impossibly complicated. continues

continued. In XRD every atom contributes to every spot detected so the intensity of every spot on the detector contains data about the position of every atom and this can be unravelled (via Fourier transforming) to give geometry.
